# how to extract specified values from a table with selenium based on a string condition

Tags: java, selenium, testing, xpath, automation

I have a table which has a column which contains:

- a list of invoices
- a column which contains a lots of charge types for every invoice displayed

What I want to do is to make a function which receives a String parameter,for example the invoice number and return all the charge types for invoice number inserted
Here is the code for the table

Every time a new invoice is displayed on the table,the first line of the table contains  and a value

That value represents the number of the charge types displayed on every invoice

For example the charge types are :Management fee,Payments,Funds Transmission Cost,Acquiring Authorisation Fee,Service etc.

```
<form method="post" action="/accounting/billing/showInvoiceTransactionsCountTotal.html? 
    jlbz=lfISHfhqWHPj5fSzCwFKoP8c5ukwXecQt0fr4iL6ak" target="detail">
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
         <tr class="odd">
            <td rowspan="8">
               <a href="/accounting/billing/showInvoice.html?invoiceNumber=BA7123399&jlbz=lfISHfhqWHPj5fSzCwFKoP8c5ukwXecQt0fr4iL6ak">
                                        BA7123399                                             
                  <input type="hidden" value="BA7123399" name="invoiceChecked"/>
               </a>
            </td>
            <td>Management fee (captured transactions)</td>
            <td>PAYPALC001M2</td>
            <td>PAYPALC001A1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>Payments</td>
            <td>PAYPALC001M2</td>
            <td>PAYPALC001A1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>Funds Transmission Cost (FTC)</td>
            <td>PAYPALC001M2</td>
            <td>PAYPALC001A1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>Acquiring Authorisation Fees</td> 
            <td>PAYPALC001M2</td>
            <td>PAYPALC001A1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>Service</td>
            <td>PAYPALC001M2</td>
            <td>PAYPALC001A1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>Refunds</td>
            <td>PAYPALC001M2</td>
            <td>PAYPALC001A1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>Chargebacks</td>
            <td>PAYPALC001M2</td>
            <td>PAYPALC001A1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>Minimum Billing</td>
            <td>PAYPALC001M2</td>
            <td>PAYPALC001A1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td rowspan="4">
                <a href="/accounting/billing/showInvoice.html?invoiceNumber=BA7123421&jlbz=lfISHfhqWHPj5fSzCwFKoP8c5ukwXecQt0fr4iL6ak">
                                        BA7123421                                             
                   <input type="hidden" value="BA7123421" name="invoiceChecked"/>
                </a>
           </td>
           <td>Payments</td>
           <td>ALEXAUTOMATION01</td>
           <td>ALEXADCODE</td>
           <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
        <tr class="even">
        <tr class="even">
        <tr class="odd">
           <td rowspan="8">
               <a href="/accounting/billing/showInvoice.html?invoiceNumber=BA7123398&jlbz=lfISHfhqWHPj5fSzCwFKoP8c5ukwXecQt0fr4iL6ak">
                                        BA7123398                                             
                   <input type="hidden" value="BA7123398" name="invoiceChecked"/>
               </a>
           </td>
           <td>Management fee (captured transactions)</td> 
           <td>PAYPALC001M2</td>
           <td>PAYPALC001A1</td>
           <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
        <tr class="odd">
        <tr class="odd">
        <tr class="odd">
        <tr class="odd">
        <tr class="odd">
        <tr class="odd">
        <tr class="even">
            <td rowspan="10">
                <a href="/accounting/billing/showInvoice.html?invoiceNumber=BA7123397&jlbz=lfISHfhqWHPj5fSzCwFKoP8c5ukwXecQt0fr4iL6ak">
                                        BA7123397                                             
                   <input type="hidden" value="BA7123397" name="invoiceChecked"/>
                </a>
           </td> 
           <td>Management fee (captured transactions)</td>
           <td>PAYPALC001M2</td>
           <td>PAYPALC001A1</td>
           <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
        <tr class="even">
        <tr class="even">
        <tr class="even">
        <tr class="even">
        <tr class="even">
        <tr class="even">
        <tr class="even">
        <tr class="even">
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some logic to achieve this scenario.since,invoice number row is missing for some of the common invoice number. Please try with the below

**Algorithm:**

```
1. Firstly,find all the row elements from the table
2. Iterate all the rowelement and match the expected Invoice Number.
3. If the Invoice Number is matched, then print all the sub sequence column charge type until next charge invoice number matches
```

**Code:**

```
    String InvoiceNumber="";
    List<String> chargetype=new ArrayList<>();
    Boolean isInvoiceSpecificCharge=false;

    //Find All the tr specific element
    List<WebElement> elementList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr"));

    for(WebElement element:elementList){
        WebElement tempElement=null;
        try{
            tempElement=element.findElement(By.xpath(".//a"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        //If the Invoice Number is present, then we need to take the charge from td[2] else from td[1].
        if(tempElement.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(InvoiceNumber)){
            isInvoiceSpecificCharge=true;
            chargetype.add(element.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[2]")).getText());
        }
        else if(tempElement==null && isInvoiceSpecificCharge ==true){
            chargetype.add(element.findElement(By.xpath(".//td")).getText());

        }else if(!tempElement.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(InvoiceNumber)){
            isInvoiceSpecificCharge=false;
        }
    }
```